# How can I extract the links from HTML?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get a link of every article in this category on the SF chronicle but I'm not sure as to where I should begin on extracting the URLs. Here is my progress so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.sfchronicle.com/local/'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
zone2_container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"zone zone-2"})
zone3_container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"zone zone-3"})
zone4_container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"zone zone-4"})
right_rail_container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"right-rail"})
```

All of the links I want are located in zone2-4_container and right_rail_container.

Comment: Just select the `href` attribute from `<a>` tags (eg: `urls = [i['href'] for i in page_soup.select('div.zone.zone-2 a')]`)

Comment: How would I be able to do this for div.zone.zone-1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get all links:

```
all_zones = [zone2_container, zone3_container, zone4_container, right_rail_container]
urls = []
for i in all_zones:
    links = i[0].findAll('a')
    for link in links:
        urls.append(link['href'])
```

---

I have merged all the lists in one list but you can also define a function to achieve the same.

```
def get_urls(zone):
    urls = []
    for i in zone:
        links = i.findAll('a')
        for link in links:
            urls.append(link['href'])
    return urls
```

`get_urls(zone2_container)`

Comment: Do you know how I can extract links if I were to have a zone1_container? It seems that it's set up differently than the other containers

Answer (score 0):

It now sounds like you basically want all the article links, in which case you can use an attribute = value css selector with contains operator to target `href` attributes whose value contains the substring '`article`'.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin
base = 'https://www.sfchronicle.com/'
url = 'https://www.sfchronicle.com/local/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
links = [urljoin(base,link['href']) for link in soup.select('[href*=article]')]
print(links)
print(len(links))
```

Comment: did you try this?